# Strange output after putting a "prime" on an identifier in Racket REPL

Tags: racket

Today, I made a typing mistake in the REPL and discovered a strange behaviour. Here's a sample of the interaction:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.11.
> (define x 3)
> x
3
> x'
3
> x
'x
>
```

So the first `x` I typed resulted in `3`, which is expected. The `x'` I accidentally typed resulted in `3`, which is unexpected. The last `x` resulted in `'x` (!!).

It seems like there is something I don't understand about how the REPL reads values. Could someone explain why the REPL behaves in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Racketrivia: Using `'` as an "identifier suffix"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/racket-users/y5OyV9Ulqv4/XiPRhvsJkj0J) on the racket mailing list. The [reply by Robby Findler](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/y5OyV9Ulqv4/8mSiIOiaBlkJ) and the [reply by Matthias Felleisen](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/y5OyV9Ulqv4/IKPmqxJTrbwJ) both explain this.

The first line, `x`, is normal.

The second line, `x'`, is actually an "expression and-a-half." It's interpreted as an expression `x` followed by an *unfinished* expression `'`. The unfinished expression is allowed to be finished on the next line. Whatever you put on the next line will be put as the second half of `' next-line`.

That means the third `x` is actually interpreted as the second half of `' x`.

You can see a better example of *unfinished* expressions with parentheses:

```
> 1 (list 2     ; 1 followed by an unfinished expression
1
> 3 4)          ; finishing it
'(2 3 4)
> 3 4)          ; on its own without the `(list 2` before it it's an error
3
4
; readline-input:13:3: read-syntax: unexpected `)` [,bt for context]
```

The quote after an expression is interpreted in a similar way:

```
> 1 '                            ; 1 followed by an unfinished expression
1
> (indefatigable inexhaustible)  ; finishes previously unfinished, put after a quote
'(indefatigable inexhaustible)
> (indefatigable inexhaustible)  ; on its own without the quote before it it's an error
; indefatigable: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: top-level
;   internal name: indefatigable
```